# what is alternative of "applet" at HTML5?

Tags: html, css

I used the "`<applet>`" tag of HTML long time ago. But after my long gap with **HTML**, while I am trying with this tag, it does not seem to be working. Does anyone know what is the alternative of "`<applet>`" tag at **HTML5**? and which browsers support it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Applet is no longer supported at **HTML5**. Just to remind you of `applet`, I have included one **`applet` example here:**

```
<applet code="Bubbles.class" width="350" height="350">
    Java applet that draws animated bubbles.
</applet>
```

Learn more about applet here: [[http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_applet.asp][1]](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_applet.asp%5d%5b1%5d)

The alternative of applet at **HTML5** is `<object>` .

The `<object>` tag defines an embedded object within an HTML document. Use this element to embed multimedia (like audio, video, Java applets, ActiveX, PDF, and Flash) in your web pages.

You can also use the `<object>` tag to embed another webpage into your HTML document.

You can use the `<param>` tag to pass parameters to plugins that have been embedded with the `<object>` tag.

***quoted from w3schools.com.

**Example of  :**

```
<object width="400" height="400" data="helloworld.swf"></object>
```

Learn more about object here [[http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_object.asp][2]](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_object.asp%5d%5b2%5d)